# Symfony2: How to make web servers root page Symfony's index page

Tags: symfony

I have multiple projects on my **example.com** server, similar to this:

```
project1/...
project2/...
symfony2/...
```

How can I make the root page - "example.com" redirect to **symfony2/web/app_dev.php** every time I run example.com?

Basicaly, my question is how to fix the routing so that Symfony's index page is my web servers root page.

I tried some .htaccess magic but it didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://example.com/web/app_dev.php
```

This only redirects me to web/app_dev.php when I run example.com, but the URL is still there in the navigation bar.

What I want is to see the web/app_dev.php open at example.com.

I apologize if the question is vaguely formed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears what I needed was the

```
DirectoryIndex web/app_dev.php
```

in .htaccess.

Now example.com always opens the Symfony index page.